# html table fields are not recognized in asp.net IDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, jquery-easyui

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j1rqbap/1)

I am trying to replicate this html code into asp.net aspx page source.
While doing so, the following table elements like `field`, `fitColumns` are not recognized by the VS IDE although the link is provided for `jeasyui.js`.

```
<table class="cartcontent" fitColumns="true" style="width:300px;height:auto;">
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
    <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
    <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
    <th field="remove" width=60 align="right">Remove</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<asp:Table> <asp:TableRow>` and `<asp:TableCell>` elements?

Comment: its working in VS 2013

Comment: @TonyHinkle what difference it makes by using `asp table` control instead of `html` when the above elements are from `jeasyui` jquery plugin?

Comment: I don't know--it was just a suggestion of something to try...

Comment: @TonyHinkle no worries mate. In a war of untie knots now :D getting slapped by downvotes left to right. It's okay if I can get things solved. But still struggling.

Comment: Don't take the downvotes personally--it's just a way to let you know that more information is needed in order for readers to help, or that someone may consider it "off topic."  Just like people on the street, though, some people here are overly critical, disrespectful, and mean.  Keep plugging away--glad you got this one figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this as per the [jeasyui documentation](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php).

```
<table class="cartcontent" 
             data-options="fitColumns:true, singleSelect: true">                                
  <thead>
       <tr>
           <th data-options="field:'name',width:100">Name</th>
           <th data-options="field:'quantity',width:100">Quantity</th>
           <th data-options="field:'balance',width:100,align:'right'">Balance</th>
           <th data-options="field:'remove',width:100,align:'right'">Remove</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```